# What built-in/standard fields are available on the `search` GraphQL query?

Tags: jss, graphql

I am trying to build a query that returns all items of a specific template, but can't seem to figure out if there's a "template" field available on the search query for GraphQL.

Where can I find a list of available fields for the GraphQL search query?

Here's what I tried:

```
{
    # 3BD4AD928374500C836811A4F049ED22 = ContentBlock template ID
    search(where: {name: "template", value: "3BD4AD928374500C836811A4F049ED22"}) {
        total
        results {
            id
            name
            path
            hasChildren
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried `templatename`, `templateid`, `templates`, `__templates`, and all the other options I could think of. They all return the following results:

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "total": 0,
      "results": []
    }
  }
}
```

### Environment details

- `jss --version`: 18.0.0
- Using the `edge` GraphQL endpoint, which uses the `edgeContent` schema configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my review of the decompiled `Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema.Services.SearchService` class (which is the service used by the `Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema.Queries.SearchQuery` query which responds to `search` queries in GraphQL), it appears that you can use any field that is present in your Solr index, but a handful of standard fields get some special treatment.

## The Solution

If you look in the Solr index (e.g. `sitecore_master_index`) you will see that the field containing the templates list is called `_templates`. The below query returns all items with a passed-in template:

```
{
    # 3BD4AD928374500C836811A4F049ED22 = ContentBlock template ID
    search(where: {name: "_templates", value: "3BD4AD928374500C836811A4F049ED22", operator: EQ}) {
        total
        results {
            id
            name
            path
            hasChildren
        }
    }
}
```

## More Info

### Special field handling

There a handful of standard fields that support a short-hand syntax, allowing you to use a default search operator and not have to pass one in. Here's the list from the `SearchService` constructor:

```
private Dictionary<string, ItemSearchOperator> supportedFields;

public SearchService(IOperationHandlerFactory operationHandlerFactory, IPaginationService paginationService)
{
    supportedFields = new Dictionary<string, ItemSearchOperator>();
    supportedFields.Add("_name", ItemSearchOperator.EQ);
    supportedFields.Add("_language", ItemSearchOperator.EQ);
    supportedFields.Add("_path", ItemSearchOperator.CONTAINS);
    supportedFields.Add("_templates", ItemSearchOperator.CONTAINS);
    supportedFields.Add("_hasLayout", ItemSearchOperator.EQ);
    supportedFields.Add("_parent", ItemSearchOperator.EQ);
    _operationHandlerFactory = operationHandlerFactory;
    _paginationService = paginationService;
}
```

Therefore, you can simplify the above query by removing the `operator: EQ` section, if you wish.

### Other fields

You can also use your own fields to search against, like so:

```
{
    # 3BD4AD928374500C836811A4F049ED22 = ContentBlock template ID
    search(
        where: {
            name: "_templates"
            value: "3BD4AD928374500C836811A4F049ED22"
            AND: { name: "heading", value: "", operator: NEQ }
        }
    ) {
        total
        results {
            id
            name
            path
            hasChildren
            fields {
                name
                value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, you can search against any other standard field in the Solr index **(just make sure you include the `operator` property)**:

```
{
    search(
        where: {
            name: "_displayname"
            value: "content"
            operator: CONTAINS
        }
    ) {
        total
        results {
            id
            name
            path
            hasChildren
            fields {
                name
                value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, also submitting a doc request for this.